# web.debug.config transform insert doesn't insert into web.config

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, web-config, web.config-transform

Maybe I'm not using the transforms correctly, I'm just learning it, but when I fetch the key like below, running in debug mode,  "stripeApiKey" is null.
When I run in debug mode and hover over "ConfigurationManager.AppSettings" I can see all the keys that are cached in memory and I don't see it! Interesting! I see it in the transformed file but it isn't getting loaded into memory. Am I missing a step somewhere?

```
string stripeApiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StripeApiKey"];
```

Here I'm trying to insert the "StripeApiKey" from the web.debug.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
 <appSettings>
    <add key="StripeApiKey" value="sk_test_mytestkey123456" 
        xdt:Transform="Insert" 
        xdt:Locator="XPath(configuration/appSettings)" 
    />
 </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Into my web.config file here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I also tried it with replace with no luck, so there must be something I'm missing in terms of location of hierarchy or something, how can I debug this?

Comment: Btw, you don't need `Locator` for `Insert`.

Comment: ok thanks but why isn't it inserting? What can I look at to try and debug this? I also tried putting in a connection string  in the "connectionStrings" area and that didn't insert it over to the we.config file either

Comment: In Visual Studio in transform file context menu should be option `Preview Transform`. Does this show expected output? Also are you running it in correct environment?

Comment: yes I believe I'm running it in debug mode. Where is the transform file context menu?

Comment: Also known as right click menu.

Comment: I'm not sure what "right click menu" is either. Do you mean right mouse click?

Comment: Yes, it's menu that appears when you right click with mouse on transformation file in Visual Studio Solution Explorer.

Comment: where does the transformation file get created? I'm running in debug mode right now and I don't see it anywhere in Solution Explorer

Comment: It should be in same place as `web.config`. It may be assigned under it and at in that case you have to collapse `web.config` to see all transformation files.

Comment: oh i see, you meant the web.debug.config file? I right clicked on it and now see the "preview transform". So in the transformed web.config file I see it! But, ok, I see it but it's not fetching it while running in debug mode because it doesn't seem to exist in the web.config file. Am I missing a step somewhere?

Comment: I can tell you that when I run in debug mode and hover over "ConfigurationManager.AppSettings" I can see all the keys that are cached in memory and I don't see it! Interesting! I see it in the transformed file but it isn't getting loaded into memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XDT transforms are not executed during normal debug sessions. They only take place when you build the project for deployment. You should put your debug values in your Web.config file, and transform them to something else in Web.Release.config (or any other build configuration you have). The syntax would also be easier, using `xdt:Locator="Match(key)"`, instead of using XPath.

Alternatively, you can use the [SlowCheetah](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscps.SlowCheetah-XMLTransforms) extension, which adds a build task that performs the transform. This will make the transformation in debug sessions too.

Comment: oh, ok, interesting! So only replace/match a transform when in release mode (production) other wise always just use debug stuff?

Comment: @user1186050 that's what I've been doing for years. I use XPath only for the more complex cases, which is pretty rare.

Comment: @user1186050 but your transform would be `SetAttributes` in this case.

Comment: what does 'setAttributes' do vs Insert or Replace? or why would I want to use setAttributes instead of replace?

Comment: Sorry for asking so many q's, but currently I'm just publishing my site in debug mode to Azure. What do I need to change/modify to "build the project for deployment"? Other than just setting the solution to release mode?

Comment: @user1186050 `Match()` is a possible value for `xdt:Locator` attribute. `Insert` or `SetAttributes` are values for the `xdt:Transform` attributes. You would want to use `SetAttributes` when you want to change the value of attributes of an existing element, rather than replace it. `Replace` is useful when the content of the element (the text node) needs to be updated. See full details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dd465326(v=vs.110))

Comment: @user1186050 Just right-click the MVC project and select Publish, and continue from there.